# VBA - Get all file paths from all subfolders in online directory

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba, directory, filepath

I would like to write a piece of VBA code that would allow me retrieve paths for all files located in all subfolders in specific online directory given.

For example the given online directory is http://cran.r-project.org/doc/ so I would like the code to open Internet Explorer and go to this directory and check all subfolders and all subfolders of this subfolders and so on and retrieve paths for all files and the dates when they were created.

I know VBA quite well but I have little experience when it comes to combining it with other applications.

Thanks in advance for all clues.

Comment: Google for "VBA automate IE" and you should get a few good starting points.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, I spend few hours playing with getelementsbytagname and so on but cannot achieve my goal, any help?

Comment: Although possible, excel is not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here another aproach with only one IE instance. In this case files are printed immediatelly, but folders are remembered into a collection and are proceeded separatelly. It is because after browser navigates to another page then the references stored in the variables like table wont work and need to be re-set. This way only table reference is needed, but not the row in the first loop. HTH.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const rootUrl As String = "http://cran.r-project.org/doc/"

Public Sub main()

    On Error GoTo err_main

    Dim browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set browser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    ReadPage browser, rootUrl

err_main:

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then _
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical

    If Not browser Is Nothing Then
        browser.Quit
        Set browser = Nothing
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ReadPage(browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, urlParam As String)

    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
    Set table = TableElement(browser, urlParam)

    If table Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No tables found in " + urlParam, vbCritical
        GoTo go_back
    End If

    Static logRow As Integer
    Dim row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
    Dim cellName As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
    Dim cellDate As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
    Dim rowIndex
    Dim urls As Collection

    Set urls = New Collection
    rowIndex = 0

    For Each row In table.Rows
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        If rowIndex <= 3 Or _
           rowIndex = table.Rows.Length Then _
            GoTo continue

        Set cellName = row.Cells(1)
        If cellName Is Nothing Then GoTo go_back

        If Right(cellName.innerText, 1) = "/" Then
            ' We are on folder, remember it
            urls.Add urlParam & cellName.innerText

        Else
            ' We are on file
            Set cellDate = row.Cells(2)
            If cellDate Is Nothing Then GoTo go_back

            logRow = logRow + 1
            Range("a" & logRow) = _
                urlParam & cellName.innerText & _
                " : " & cellDate.innerText
        End If
continue:
    Next row

    Dim url
    ' loopt through folders
    For Each url In urls
        ReadPage browser, CStr(url)
    Next url

go_back:
    If Not urlParam = rootUrl Then
        Set table = TableElement(browser, isGoBack:=True)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function TableElement(browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, _
    Optional urlParam As String, Optional isGoBack = False) _
    As MSHTML.HTMLTable

    If isGoBack Then
        browser.GoBack
    Else
        browser.navigate urlParam
    End If

    Do Until (browser.readyState = 4 And Not browser.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    On Error Resume Next
    Set TableElement = browser.document.getElementsByTagName("Table")(0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: I have to go to work soon so I will check how it works later. Thanks for help!

Comment: I have checked it and it works great! Thank you so much! Unfortunatelly I cannot upvote your answer due to lack of reputation... I tells me that I need 15 points of rep tu upvote you but I don't... I check you second answer as the best, thanks once again, you're great at this and you've made me aware how much I have to learn to perfect this stuff. I have one little problem. Macro sometimes stops at browser.readystate and not browser.busy part although browser is done with work. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: 15 points I see :-). No problem, it's just fine. Yes with the ready-state there are problems somethimes and works not reliable :-(. Try to google it, hope you will be able to find some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how this could be done.
The code starts on root-url and searches for table elements by tag name. Takes first table and loops through rows except first three and last one (which do not contain any data). In the data-row then takes second and third cell for name and date values. If name ends with slash then it is considered to be a folder and the function 'ReadPage' is recursively called and url of the root plus folder name are passed to it. If no slash is in the cell value then it is considered to be date-cell and then we can print information about path and date.

Each instance of the function 'ReadPage' opens its own IE window, so finally this window is closed. HTH.

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls and to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Option Explicit

Private Const rootUrl As String = "http://cran.r-project.org/doc/"

Public Sub main()

    On Error GoTo err_main

    ReadPage rootUrl

err_main:

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then _
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical

End Sub

Private Sub ReadPage(url As String)

    Dim browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set browser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    browser.Visible = True
    browser.navigate url

    Do Until (browser.readyState = 4 And Not browser.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set document = browser.document

    Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Set tables = document.getElementsByTagName("Table")
    If tables.Length <= 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No tables found in " + url
        GoTo quit_me
    End If

    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
    Set table = tables(0)

    Dim row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
    Dim cellName As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
    Dim cellDate As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
    Dim rowIndex

    rowIndex = 0
    For Each row In table.Rows
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        If rowIndex <= 3 Or rowIndex = table.Rows.Length Then GoTo continue

        Set cellName = row.Cells(1)
        If cellName Is Nothing Then GoTo quit_me

        If Right(cellName.innerText, 1) = "/" Then
            ' We are on folder
            ReadPage url & cellName.innerText
            Debug.Print "Finished with Url " & url & cellName.innerText
        Else
            ' We are on file
            Set cellDate = row.Cells(2)
            If cellDate Is Nothing Then GoTo quit_me

            Debug.Print url & cellName.innerText & " : " & cellDate.innerText
        End If
continue:
    Next row

quit_me:
    If Not browser Is Nothing Then
        browser.Quit
        Set browser = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, that helps a lot and works like a charm! Thank you so much! How can I give you some reputation points or something like that? I have one other question. Is it possible to open new urls in the same instance of IE but on the new tabs?

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-). You could up-vote the answer that will give me some extra points, thanks! To open the url in new tab try this: IE.Navigate URL, BrowserNavConstants.navOpenInNewTab

Comment: I will try that tommorow but when code goes to quit_me: part it would close my browser so another subdirectory will open in new instance of IE. Before scraping all files from subfolder I have to log to the page and I'm not sure if opening every subfolder in new instance would keep me logged in. The best way would be to open all windows that now are opened in new instances, in one instance or even on one tab. Is it possible?

Comment: Heve added another answer which uses only one IE instance. You can of course still up-vote both answers :-).